# how can i change String array to String

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] test={"this","this2"};
        new Test().it(test);
    }

    public int it(String[] name)
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(name[0]);
    }
}
```

I want to change String array to String.I get the exception like this Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "this"
    //String change = name[0];
    // return Integer.parseInt(change);

it this code only solve the problem?

Comment: you are using string this to parse in integer

Comment: You have to parse to string not int

Comment: Try this  if really want to convert string `String res = Arrays.toString(array);`

Comment: how the hell "this" or "this2" will be parsed as a number,it will obviously throw number format exception. what you are asking and what you wrote in code doesn't make sense at all

Comment: Why are you trying to turn a string into an integer? There is no way letters can ever be a numbers so of course you will get an number format exception. Just return a string instead. It's what you said you wanted

Comment: Even ignoring the string-to-integer problem, you haven't made it clear what `String` you would want returned. Just what do you mean by "change a String array to a String"?  You need to explain.

Comment: Brother you always u getting NumberFormateException because in parameter of your method you pass String and that method will return Integer how can it possible?

If you want to parse String value in to integer then you should be have to pass a numeric value Like : "1","3"....etc

Comment: Thank you, I will try every thing.
sorry to my explain my problem.
"Change  a String array to a String" means i want to use String API like String.(something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code to convert string array to string

```
    public class JavaApplication20 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        String test1 = "";
        String[] test = {"this","this2"};
        int length = test.length;
        //System.out.println("Length :"+length);
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
            //System.out.println(test[i]);
            test1 += test[i]+",";
        }
        int len = test1.length();
        String str = test1.substring(0, len-1);
        System.out.println("String :"+str);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank u for command. but i ready use this code. but that is too long for me. 
I want to use only one command line.  your answer is very good.